# Problem in connecting SQL and PHP/HTML by a form

Tags: php, html, sql

I'm trying to build social network database, but i have some problems in inserting values into `user_` table.

Database is already there but no updates to it (No output code when redirecting to `PHP/signup.php`) and also no new rows affected by inserting to database.

I'm newbie to `PHP` so i guess i have mistakes but i can't figure it out, please help me.

My file hire-achy is

```
-css

-js

-img

-PHP

 -- signup.php

 -- login.php

-signup.html

-login.html
```

My HTML code

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Signup for facebook! </title>
  <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:400,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/normalize/5.0.0/normalize.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/signup.css">

</head>

<body>

  <section class="logina-form-wrap">
    <h1>Facebook</h1>
    <form class="login-form" action="./PHP/signup.php" method="post">
      <label>
        <input type="text" name="firstName" required placeholder="First Name">
      </label>
      <label>
        <input type="text" name="lastName" required placeholder="Last Name">
      </label>
      <label>
        <input type="text" name="nickName" placeholder="Nick Name">
      </label>
      <label>
        <input type="password" name="Password" required placeholder="Password">
      </label>
      <label>
        <input type="tel" name="phoneNumber" placeholder="Phone">
      </label>
      <label>
        <input type="email" name="Email" required placeholder="Email">
      </label>
      <label>
        <input list="sex-s" name="sex" required placeholder="Sex">
        <datalist id="sex-s">
          <option value="Male">
          <option value="Female">
          <option value="Not determined">
        </datalist>
      </label>
      <label>
        <input type="date" name="bday" required placeholder="Birthday">
      </label>
      <label style="color:white;">
        Upload your image!
        <input id = "uploadBox" type="file" name="pic" accept="image/*">
      </label>
      <label>
        <input type="text" name="homeTown" placeholder="Home Town">
      </label>
      <label>
        <input list="marital" name="status" placeholder="Marital Status">
        <datalist id="marital">
          <option value="Single">
          <option value="Engaged">
          <option value="Married">
        </datalist>
      </label>
      <label>
        <textarea rows="4" cols="31" name="me" placeholder="About You." style="margin: 5px auto 0 auto;"></textarea>
      </label>
      <input type="submit" value="Register" name="register_">
    </form>
  </section>
</body>

</html>
```

My PHP code.

```php
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "username";
$password = "";
$db="socialnetwork";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password,$db);

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error)
    {
        echo("Failed");
        die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
    } 

else
    {
        echo("?");
        if (isset($_POST['register_']))
        {
            $firstname=$_POST['firstName'];
            $lastname=$_POST['lastName'];
            $nickname=$_POST['nickName'];
            $password=$_POST['Password'];
            $email=$_POST['Email'];
            $gender=$_POST['sex'];
            $hometown=$_POST['homeTown'];
            $phone=$_POST['phoneNumber'];
            $birtdate=$_POST['bday'];
            $aboutme=$_POST['me'];
            $mstatus=$_POST['status'];
            $image=$_FILES['pic']['name'];
            if ($_FILES['pic']['name'] == ""){
                if($gender == 1){
                $image = "./img/female_default";
                }
                else{
                $image = "./img/male_default";
                }

            }
            $sql="INSERT INTO user_(first_name, last_name, nick_name, pass_word, user_email, phone_number, home_town, about_me, user_status, birth_date, user_gender, number_friends, user_image) VALUES ('$firstname','$lastname','$nickname','$password','$email','$phone','$hometown','$aboutme','$mstatus','$birtdate','$gender', 10, '$image')";
            $qry=mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
            if($qry){
                echo "done";
            }


        }
   $conn->close();
}

?>
```

My SQL file

```SQL
create database socialnetwork;
CREATE TABLE if not exists user_(
    first_name varchar(255) not null,
    last_name varchar(255) not null,
    nick_name varchar(255),
    pass_word varchar not null,
    user_email varchar(255) unique not null,
    phone_number varchar(255),
    home_town varchar(255) ,
    about_me varchar(255) ,
    user_status varchar(255),
    birth_date varchar(255),
    user_gender varchar(255),
    number_friends int , 
    user_image VARBINARY (10000000),
    PRIMARY KEY (user_email)
);
```

Comment: Use error reporting it will tell you what is wrong. Dont put use input in SQL. Use parameterized queries. Don't store plain text passwords, hash them. 1. https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php 2. https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php 3. https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php

Comment: How can i use error reporting?

Comment: See the provided links at the end of the comment. (Refresh if not available)

Comment: If you just start your project: think of some strategies first. Do you really want to hardcode database credentials in each and every file?

Answer (score 0):

Problem was:
You have to set your project in `htdocs` folder in your `XAMPP` folder.